# Samda/Winbind Active Directory Failover Not Working - Winbind Stops Responding

Tags: ubuntu, samba, winbind

Ubuntu 20.04

Samba/Winbind Version: 4.15.13-Ubuntu

I'm having an odd issue with Sambda/Winbindd that I can't seem to figure out. We have multiple windows domain controllers within our network (all reachable by the linux VM running Samba that is successfully domain joined). If the domain controller the samba client is currently connected to goes down (reboot, etc.), authentication stops working on the linux VM.

There are plenty of posts/articles on the internet about this, but I haven't found any suggestions that fix the issue.

- The DNS resolver on the system is configured with multiple DNS servers

  - Name Resolution does not appear to be an issue when one of the domain controllers becomes unavailable
- Samba is configured to query SRV records (dns_lookup_kdc = true)
- password server is set to the default "*" (recommended config I believe)

I simulate the issue by simply putting in an iptable entry to block traffic to the connected DC.

```
wbinfo -P
#Get current DC
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <fqdn> -j DROP
```

Once the iptable entry is in, wbinfo -P starts to fail/hang. Attempting to SSH into the server hangs. At some point (maybe 10-20 minutes), things magically fix themselves and it seems samba/winbind finally fails over.

I guess my main questions are:

1. Is there any way to improve the failover speed? It seems things should failover faster/more consistently than this.
2. Is there any other configuration options related to realms/domains/kdcs/etc. I should be trying in smb.conf?

Samba/Winbind otherwise work fine in this environment. I just can't nail down the root cause of this failover issue.